# How to optimize website for Chrome: waiting and download order of magnitude slower than other browsers

Tags: google-chrome, amazon-cloudfront

NB: since the answer to this could involve JavaScript or PHP programming, or general networking, or IT systems, I put it here, but if some mod thinks it's better suited for SuperUser or ServerFault, I won't object to it being moved.

I have a landing page to which I'm driving traffic through PPC. I've set up AWS CloudWatch to get [RUM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_user_monitoring) data, and the page is performing terribly — an average load time of 9.9s and max of 21.5!

I've done all of the "standard" optimization I can think of or research. The site is built with WordPress, running on Apache on an EC2 server. I've

- Upgraded the EC2 instance to ensure I have enough memory
- Written a custom plugin to filter out any other plugins that aren't explicitly used on the landing page in question
- Customised my theme code so that it sets proper `srcset` and creates the correct image sizes on upload
- Minified all the JS and CSS that I include through plugins or themes I've written
- Put the site itself as a distribution to CloudFront
- Installed the WP Super Cache plugin, and created a separate CDN distribution on CloudFront for it
- Set appropriate `cache control` headers on CloudFront and told it to gzip everything
- Put a [facade](https://web.dev/third-party-facades/) in place of any videos

The site is blazing fast for me — "load" is less than 1 second. But my RUM says that's not the case for my users. So, I dug a little deeper. 70.2% of my visitors use Chrome, and 27.7% use other, of which almost 1/3rd are Android Browser — which as I understand it is just some sort of "Chrome Lite" — so nearly 80% of my visitors are using some Chrome variant.

Sure enough — if I load the page on Safari (to ensure nothing has expired on CloudFront), clear my browser cache, and reload the page, the first request shows a waiting time of 21.2ms, TTFB of 22.6ms, and download time of 4.8ms. The whole page shows that it's finished loading in 973ms.

Firefox is slightly slower, with the first request taking 100ms total, and the whole load about 1.75s — not blazing fast, but still within the understood "2 second" limit for good user experience.

On the other hand, for Chrome that same first request takes almost 570ms waiting and 208ms download. So, just the first request (which is 36k in size) takes almost as long to load in Chrome as the whole site takes in Safari. And that repeats for every single request, where both the waiting time and the download time are an order of magnitude slower on Chrome than on Safari (on the same device on the same network):

[image]

Whereas on Safari:

[image]

I would think "waiting" and "download" times would be primarily network driven, but I can repeat this all day long and the results are the same.

I might just assume that Chrome is not optimized for the Mac on which I'm running it, but, as I said, this all started with RUM data, so it's clearly not that. As much as I might like to, I obviously can't force all of my visitors to swap their Android devices for iPhones. Equally obviously, I can't have an average load time of 10 seconds.

So, why is my site so slow on Chrome? What else can I do to optimize this?

The landing page in question is here: https://www.chrisrichardson.info/lp/prague-b/

Note, a lot of the optimization I've done is for that page in particular, so other pages on the site might perform even worse, but I don't care about that, at least at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Hahahaha.

OK, just leaving this here for posterity's sake. The 10x latency was because Chrome had preserved in devtools from a previous session throttling to 3G. So, if you stumble upon this problem, check your throttling.

That still doesn't address my RUM issue, however, but I'll open that up as a different question.